# Push value into a List

Tags: list, groovy

Lets say I have list of values..

```
List values = [["A","A"],["B","B"],["C","C"],["D","D"]]
```

and I would like to push a value, **"*"**,  into the list so it looks like this

```
[["*", "A","A"],["*", "B","B"],["*", "C","C"],["*", "D","D"]]
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The star-dot method may help. It would look like this:

```
values*.addAll(0, "*")
```

The docs could use some improvement here. :)

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
values.collect { [ '*' ] + it }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested,

this seem to work:

```
List values = [["A","A"],["B","B"],["C","C"],["D","D"]]

values.each{
 it.addAll(0,"*")
}

println values
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[[*, A, A], [*, B, B], [*, C, C], [*, D, D]]
```